# How many intersections does an n-sided polygon's diagonal have if no 3 diagonals intersect.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Let $P$ denote a convex $n$-sided polygon in which no three diagonals intersect in a single point.
How many intersection points do the diagonals of $P$ have?

Trying to derive a formula, starting with a thought experiment to see a pattern

Quadrilateral/ 2 diagonals, 1 point of intersection

Pentagon/ 5 diagonals, 5 points of intersection

Hexagon/ 9 diagonals, 15 points of intersection

Comment: But hexagon has 3 diagonals intersect at a single point.

Comment: @FtyRain: The hexagon doesn't have to be regular.

Comment: See also an article about concurrent diagonals for regular $n$-gon [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simply $\binom{n}{4}$, because a set of four vertices of the polygon *uniquely* determines a pair of intersecting diagonals, and therefore (by the "three diagonals" condition) their intersection point.